# how to get python3 safely on any platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

we have a bunch of code in python - we have a sort of bootstrap bash script that kicks off various things - and we are trying to just set a python_bin variable that points to python 3.  I tried this:

```bash
if [[ $( which python 2>/dev/null ) =~ /Python3 ]]; then
    python_bin=python
elif which python3 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    python_bin=python3
else
    python_bin=python
fi
```

but on some windows boxes it's not finding the right python because it's behind some runner "py".     Is there a definitive way in bash to get to python3 that works on any platform where python and bash are both installed in the path?

Basically we want someone to be able to get clone our repository and run setup.sh - and keep finding environments where the python install is different in some new and interesting way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "safely"? What specific problems or risks are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a definitive way in bash to get to python3 that works on any platform where python and bash are both installed in the path?

First off, are you sure that's sufficient? There could be any number of Python installations within folders that are on the PATH. For that matter, are you sure that your script will run correctly even under 3.0?

Second, no, you can't ever do this in a completely foolproof way. For one thing, Windows users are under no compulsion to leave `python.exe`'s name alone. After all, nothing in Windows is dependent upon it. Linux and Mac users even have the same freedom for other installations besides the system one. For another, just because a system has Python installed doesn't mean it has any 3.x installations.

(Oh, and you should probably take a moment to make sure you understand how virtual environments work, and do some testing with those. Depending on the platform and the user's preferences, these might either copy the base Python environment or symlink it. Then there are all the alternate implementations: Jython, Pypy, IronPython....)

On the other hand, 2.7 has been EOL for over two years; it is approximately as old as Windows 7. Your users should be expecting any new code to demand 3.x anyway - and a reasonably up-to-date version at that. Even 3.6 is EOL now.

> some windows boxes it's not finding the right python because it's behind some runner "py".

Keep in mind that if you are using Bash on Windows then you are effectively reliant on hacks anyway. I would recommend writing a separate .bat version of the bootstrap, if possible.

The [Python launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) exists because Windows does not have a built-in concept of shebang lines. Not everyone on Windows uses it. The entire point of `py` is that it circumvents the PATH environment variable; `py` itself is on the path (typically in the Windows install directory, for global installations), and it maintains its own registry. It does this exactly in order to support more complex logic for choosing an executable; using PATH can only ever give you the first valid thing that was found. Systems that use `py` will generally not put any of their installed Python installations on the PATH, because `py` will take care of it. But they could, and *who knows* which one will be found first.

If you *really* want to stick with this detection logic, try prioritizing a search for `py`, and use `py -3` if `py` is available. But...

> Basically we want someone to be able to get clone our repository and run setup.sh - and keep finding environments where the python install is different in some new and interesting way.

The best you can do is to just write a shebang line, set the executable bit for the script on systems that support it, use the Bash script to run these executable scripts as scripts (rather than trying to find the Python executable), and *let users be responsible for their own environment variables*. People who set up their environments in weird ways are supposed to be responsible for understanding the weirdness. I appreciate the desire to try to provide a turn-key solution for people who might not be that technically proficient - but if your audience includes the sort of person who installs Bash on Windows, there are at least some reasonable guarantees on technical proficiency.

On ordinary Linux and Mac setups, a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env python3` should give you the default 3.x Python in the current context. Such a shebang is also recognized by `py`, which will parse it in a completely different way: the `.py` file extension is registered to be run by `py`; `py` sees the shebang and applies some regexes; it sees that the command includes `python3`, and runs whichever Python it has registered as the default 3.x installation.

Comment: thanks - that's useful - although I was dreaming of a simple canonical answer.    we do want to find the exe - precisely because of things like virtual environments - we do a $python_bin -m venv among many other things.   Think I'll just check for py at the moment and keep adding cases as they come up.   I'm less happy with the shebang because we have many people using the code, and it's more room for errors - in the main runner script it's only one place, even though it runs _many_ python scripts.

Comment: also - it's not even as simple as "my users" - even just me...  each time we've created a new type of CI box, because we use pyinstallers to create exes - we've had a new type of error.  amazon  linux boxes seem to think python means 2.7 for instance

Comment: "precisely because of things like virtual environments" If a virtual environment is active, that is because the user wants Python scripts to run in that environment. The shebang is the closest thing you're going to get to a "simple canonical answer". It only has to go on each Python source file that is an *entry point* needing to be run by the script. It has nothing to do with the number of users you have.

Comment: If you are creating exes using pyinstaller, then I don't understand why there is any question of finding a python executable in the first place. At worst you'd have to ship a `.dll`/`.so` for the appropriate python version along with the executable, I would think.

Comment: the reason I mention the number of users - is if we start relying on the shebang - that means that we have to rely on new users/devs remembering to _put_ the shebang at the start of any new entry point - there are many entry points, many devs.  it will be missed

Comment: Ah. Well, I don't know how big your codebase is etc., but that is one of those "best practices" sorts of things anyway. Point your team leaders at some of the https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shebang+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion search results if necessary.

Comment: the problem is on the CI - no people involved - so far the experience has been "create a new type of build box, setup a github runner - run it - watch the thing go bang because it's it's found the wrong version of python, or python isn't found, or pip isn't working".   Every single time.  ie its where we are _running_ pyinstaller - not using it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246326/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-darren-oakey).